# Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "WebKitBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, webkit

Подключил длл Webkitbrowser и добавил элемент. Но при запуске выдает эту ошибку.

Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "WebKitBrowser, Version=0.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b967213f6d29a3be" либо одну из их зависимостей. Была сделана попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего это из-за того, что WebKitBrowser предназначен для 32 битных приложений. Попробуйте сменить целевую платформу для проекта. Для этого правой кнопкой по проекту -> свойства -> сборка -> и выбрать цель платформы "x86".

Подробнее на [странице](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/basics.php?p=4):

> Changing the Application Platform
>   As there is no x64 build of WebKit yet, WebKit .NET is configured to run only as a 32-bit process so that it functions correctly on 64-bit versions of Windows. As a consequence of this, ALL .NET applications which use WebKit .NET must also be configured in this way. By default, C# applications will run as a 64-bit process on Win64, and we will get an error if we try to use a 32-bit library with them. To change the platform, right click the project in the Solution Explorer and select 'Properties'. Select the 'Build' tab and choose 'x86' as the platform (by default it will be set to 'Any CPU').

Comment: Спасибо, помогло